# Facebook Login Button - how to authenticate user?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication

I have added a [facebook login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login).

After authenticating I get the following parameters passed via Javascript:

```
"status": "connected",
   "session": {
      "uid": "...",
      "session_key": "...",
      "secret": "...",
      "expires": 000,
      "base_domain": "...",
      "access_token": "...",
      "sig": "..."
   }
```

I plan to post these to a new page and authenticate to login the user, but unsure which ones I should use as I can't find any documentation for this.

How can I securely authenticate a user from this information?

Answer (score 0):

Just the `access_token`. Facebook Graph API is simple enough. Just spend some time with it :)

Comment: Do you mean simply retrieving using https://graph.facebook.com/me with the access token?

Comment: @Pool: yep: what exactly is you problem?

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing but I believed I needed to use the app secret at some stage?

Comment: no. grpah api has two flows. server side and client side. whats the point in passing app_secret in client side flow. everyone can see that anyway :)

Comment: Indeed. Currently, I am posting the details to server and thought I would check the app secret there.

Comment: This can have a problem though, anyone who has a valid access token for a user in a different site could pretend to be them in my site.

Comment: Hi Naveen, but there's no point that the redirect_uri can be used? I think I'm missing something here.